# error deploying dns in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

when I run `sudo ./deployAddons.sh` under `kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu` I get the following:

```
replicationcontroller "kube-dns-v14" created
The Service "kube-dns" is invalid.
spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "192.168.3.10": provided IP is not in the valid range
```

Where to set this?(which file) and what variable to set?

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.3.10` is the default IP used in the ubuntu deployment (defined [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh#L99). You should override it by setting the `DNS_SERVER_IP` environment variable. It's value can be any unused value in the cluster IP range, but should match what the kubelets were started with (using the `--cluster-dns` flag). See the [DNS readme](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/addons/dns/README.md) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I am using ubuntu locally on a virtual box what should I set that value to?

Comment: I use kubectl and I am not sure what value is passed to kubelets but when I go kubectl get nodes all I see is "127.0.0.1 running"

Comment: I'm not sure, but `127.0.0.1` might work in this case. Have you tried the [Vagrant getting started guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant/)?

Comment: replicationcontroller "kube-dns-v14" created
The Service "kube-dns" is invalid.
spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": provided IP is not in the valid range

Comment: How did you setup the cluster? The cluster config usually includes a `CLUSTER_IP_RANGE` environment variable which defines the valid range.

Comment: I just ran hack/local_cluster_up.sh

Comment: export SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE=${SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE:-192.168.3.0/24} (This is what defined under config-default.sh). Should I set this to DNS_SERVER_IP?

Comment: If you're not the one who asked it, there's a thread addressing this same issue over on the [google-containers group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/d7CBdPagD3E)